# how to ask for document properties only if another property is first assigned

Tags: document-library, properties

for example, property #1 is "color," with the choices blue or green. property #2 is "hue." if someone selects "blue" for the "color," then their options for "hue" are navy and aqua, whereas if the "color" is "green," the hue can be forest or army.

i haven't found a way to do this on the same subsite, even within different folders or document libraries (since all files are ultimately stored in Team Docs). do i need to create separate sites for each "color," then ask for properties individually from there?

there's got to be a better way to do this. i don't want to confuse my users.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to cascading drop downs in that values from one field filter the available options in another field. Sharepoint doesn't give you this type of functionality. It can be achieved with script (like [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation)) or [Infopath](http://basquang.wordpress.com/2010/03/29/cascading-drop-down-list-in-sharepoint-2010-using-infopath-2010/).